# can virtio-net device write into descriptor table

Tags: virtio

Can the virtio-net device that's part of the VMM, write into the descriptor table entries or are they limited to only populating the used rings?

Secondly is the typical use for there to be 2 descriptor tables, one for the Rx path and one for the Tx or can they be shared with appropriate locking?